# Which unittest framework is integrated into Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Visual Studio 2008 has built-in unittesting that was previously only available in the Team Suite editions. What unittesting framework is this based on? MbUint, MStest, xUnit or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSTest is included with VS2008, as it was with Dev. edt. and Test edt. in VS2005.

Answer (score 2):

It's MS Test. Would you expect it to be anything else? It would be a bit like MS deciding to use NAnt instead of MS Build ;)

On the other hand, I seem to remember that ASP.NET MVC has unit testing options for MS Test, NUnit and MbUnit. I haven't used it myself, so that information is purely based on screenshots.

Personally I think MS could have sewn up the unit test framework market in 2005 if they'd given MS test a bit more polish (like a red/green bar!) and included it in the Express edition. The fact that it's available in Pro now is a good start, but there's still a message of "unit testing isn't for hobbyists" which I find somewhat annoying :(

Comment: Agree! It should be available in all editions. In fact I think they should build tools like that as MEF extensions; that would make it possible for the "community" to replace the tools included in VS.